# Smart Card Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, certificate

I'm developing an ASP-MVC Application, that uses a smart card authentication to authorize the user for specific pages (views). I've written the code and right now I'm trying to test it in a debugger mode. I've installed a smart card reader on my machine and my code looks like that:

```
string certHeaderName = "certificate";
if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[certHeaderName] != null) {
   string certificate=HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[certHeaderName];
   certToParse = Convert.FromBase64String(certificate);
}
```

And for some reason, this header does not present. I only have the following headers:

- Cache-Control
- connection
- content-length
- content-type
- Accept
- Accept-Encoding
- Accept-Language
- Cookie
- Host
- Referer
- user-agent
- origin

I've tested the smart card I have for testing porpuses, and it is indeed valid:

[image]

I'm not sure, maybe I need to install some plug-in for my browser or something...